# Bootstrap grid classes ignored

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap grid system to create 3-grid fixed vertical navigation tabs on the left and 9-grid normal flow contents on the right. However, it seems all the class .col-*-* or offset-*-* are ignored. I checked that on the other elements, the bootstrap.min.css stylings were applied fine but I only can't use column classes. Is there any reason that might be causing this bug?
The code below is the simple code I included in my file but still doesn't work. Even though .container-fluid and .row is applied fine, it doesn't recognise .col-*-*  Thank you.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: if you have added your bootstrap.min.ccs file and the jquery and bootstrap javascript files and it's still the same, you may need to remove the fluid in your parent div that is, use class="container" instead of "container-fluid"

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap columns need JavaScript. Have you linked the JavaScript file and JQuery (because Bootstrap needs JQuery to run)? Make sure to load JQuery before the Bootstrap JavaScript.

From my own project:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="assets/jquery/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I included script tags in the end of body section by copy and pasting from Bootstrap's introduction page. (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/#js). I also have jquery and bootstrap.min.js locally though. Is it better to use local file? When I used local file and tried to run the Bootstrap examples code, it didn't work. The columns also still not working. Is there any other possible cause? Thank you.

Comment: I personally place these within the <head> tags instead of the body: maybe you could try that? I'm no pro, but I don't think there's a huge difference between including the files locally or fetching them from a server: I added them locally too and it worked fine. Maybe someone knows more about the differences than me, but both should work. I do think your issue is related to JavaScript though, because the rest works fine.

Comment: I tried placing them in head section but still does not work. I will post a new thread to ask question that focuses more about including JavaScript. Thank you so much for the answer and reply!